# Redirecting Users or Aborting

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a directory on a site I built in asp.net a long time ago and had many aspx pages inside a certain directory which I have deleted including the actual directory, removed the info from the sitemap and denied access to it in robots.txt. If I go to Webmaster Tools I see lots of errors even after 90 days as these pages no longer exist and if I look in the IIS logs the visitors are receiving error 500 (server error) messages. In Webmaster Tools you can hide individual pages from the search for a while or cache but that's not a permanent solution. I searched the net and haven't found a solution to it and there is no point asking on asp.net or iis.net sites as they will just open google, type a few keywords then just paste any ole line in, which will only waste my time an theirs. So, does anyone know how to block an entire directory in the IIS Rewriting module.

http://www.example.com/deleted_directory/every_aspx_page.aspx
http://www.example.com/deleted_directory/*

to

http://www.example.com/404.aspx

I know the action could either be Abort Request or Permanent

Anyone know what the exact URL Rewrite rule would be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx).
You could filter your "/deleted_directory/" and forward to the 404.aspx page.

or

You could put that to the webconfig and it will handle the 500 (server error).

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Default.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Default.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/404.aspx" />
     <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/400.aspx" />
     <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

or

You could put that to the Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
        if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            HttpException httpexc = (HttpException)exc;
            if (httpexc.GetHttpCode() == 500 && Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("deleted_directory/"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/404.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ther error page default doc has been in place for 7 years and the 403/404 work fine but it never redirects to the 500 error page. On mine, Moder is ON not RemoteOnly The routing was attempted around 1 year ago and the entire site goes down with a 500 internal server error. The entire site will be re-written within the next year but it won't stop users trying to visit the directory which doesn't exist. If I add that directory back in and navigate to it I get a 403 (correct) and if I make up a page name I redirect to 404 (correct) but I need to remove the directory and redirect or abort

Comment: @EssexMale I added a new solution to the answer.

Comment: Site won't let me edit my last comment after 5.5 mins (only under 5) this is the info. I tried previously to see if the path contains that removed directory in the BeginRequest sub in Global.asax then redirect or abort request but that never worked. Looking at your C# (I use VB) code I can see this isn't going to be any good either because if there is a contacting a db or other error in the WebApp you will redirect everyone to say page doesn't exist when they do. To use your code I will need to check if a request to that directory then redirect. Also Catch (ex As HttpException) is usual.

Comment: Yes you are right you should check the request. I edited my answer. Is it working for you?

Comment: Thanks again for replying. That deleted_directory code you done is what I had in vb.net yesterday in the BeginRequest sub where it wouldn't find it. This kind of does what I want in a way:<br />Dim thisURL As String = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower<br />
If thisURL.StartsWith("/deleted_directory_name/") Then Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx") 'Else Response.Redirect("~/500.aspx"). The code you so kindly wrote doesn't override the 500 and redirect to 404. If I write a test page and use your CONTAINS code to write a response in an if statement it always returns false even when converting to lower

Comment: Your code returns Nothing (NULL), hence it isn't working and so does this: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. If I use your declaration for httpexc then httpexc.GetHttpCode I get 500.Application_Error don't seem to be called nor does Page_Error. I ever checked this: Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError Response.Write(ex.ToString()) & it's Nothing (NULL)

Answer (score 0):

I answered this by creating a URL Rewrite to abort requests to that folder, which is exactly what I wanted in the first place. I found the sort of answer on IIS & ASP net sites